# PyQT on Mac Mountain Lion - Can't create new QApplication

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to learn PyQT and have installed QT, SIP, and PyQT without much trouble.

However while trying to follow some basic tutorials, I can't even create a QApplication, i.e.:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<pyshell#376>", line 1, in <module>
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

If I do a:

dir(QtGui)

I don't see QApplication listed.

Do I need to do something (i.e. another configuration step, etc.) first before this works?

Comment: Please format code by adding four spaces in front of each line, that makes it readable way better.

Comment: In the python terminal, type `import PyQt4`, then `print PyQt4.__file__`.  This will show the path to the PyQt4 library.  Look in that path to see if there is a QApplication file in the QGui folder.

Comment: I did the print PyQt4.__file__ and got back /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.py, which is the location I was expecting. However, that location does not contain a a QtGui folder - only a file called QtGui.so.